# Editing a .jar with `vim`

Tags: linux, vim, jar

On an Amazon Linux instance I'm trying to edit a jar file remotely through putty. `vim` provides a convenient navigator, which displays a prompt with a list of the contained files in the jar:

```
> vim filename.jar

" zip.vim version v22
" Browsing zipfile /home/ec2-user/tigase/libs/tigase-muc.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

      453  01-14-2013 10:01   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      110  01-14-2013 10:01   META-INF/maven/tigase/tigase-muc/pom.properties
     4675  01-14-2013 10:01   META-INF/maven/tigase/tigase-muc/pom.xml
     5751  01-14-2013 10:01   tigase/component/AbstractComponent.class
     2337  01-14-2013 10:01   tigase/component/AbstractComponent$1.class
     ....
```

However after selecting a file (eg. AbstractComponent.class) and press Enter, within vim I get:

```
caution: filename not matched:       5751  01-14-2013 10:01   tigase/component/AbstractComponent.class
```

and the file doesn't open.

As a side note, I also noticed that if I extract the jar (either with `unzip` or `jar`) and open an extracted file with vim, the contents are misformatted:

```
Êþº¾^@^@^@2^A^[^H^@     ^H^@
^H^@^K^H^@^U^H^@^V^H^@!^H^@#^H^@^^A^@) stanza already with type='...
^A^@^C()I^A^@^C()V^A^@^C()Z^A^@^F<init>^A^@^NDEFAULT_WRITER^A^@^WFE...
....
```

Any ideas how to overcome the error or formatting issue?

Comment: You are aware that jar is basically a zip, and that .class files are Java bytecode files? Meaning they're not text files, but inly data containers and you'd need a decompiled (or a hex editor and a steady eye) to read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However after selecting a file (eg. AbstractComponent.class) and press
>   Enter, within vim I get:
>
> caution: filename not matched

This is probably a known bug in vim's ZIP plugin - the plugin does not properly handle ZIP files that contain ZIP comments. See e.g. [this mailing list post](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vimdev/conversations/topics/60156)

> As a side note, I also noticed that if I extract the jar (either with
>   unzip or jar) and open an extracted file with vim, the contents are
>   misformatted

This is because most files inside a JAR are compiled Java class files (file suffix `.class`). These are binary data, and vim is not really suitable for editing them, because vim is a *text* editor, not a binary editor.

You can edit them in vim using the `xxd` command (see "Using xxd" in the [vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_23.html)), or you can use a hex editor, such as [bvi](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/).

At any rate, directly viewing the contents of a class file is rarely helpful, as you need to understand the binary class file format to read them.

Could you explain why you are trying to open files inside a JAR? Then maybe we can help.

Comment: 'grats on 10k!~

Comment: I had apparently spaced out thinking of .java as of .class (compiled binaries) and expecting to be able to edit those files directly, i.e. not needing to extract - edit - compress. I will look up and try 'xxd', thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Sathya: Thanks, I just got the message :-).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the formatting issues.

First install emacs

```
 yum install emacs
```

Then use below command to read the content

```
emacs somejar.jar
```

select the content and press `Enter`

To save and quit from the editor, press C-x C-s (Ctrl+x, followed by Ctrl+s).

Source :  [How To Use the Emacs Editor in Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-emacs-editor-in-linux)

Comment: The question is about how do this job with `vim`.

Comment: This answer is not on topic, doesn't help the community, and follows the pattern: have one (small?) problem with X — plz switch and start using Y.

Comment: This is where people lecture me on the "X -> Y" problem of stack overflow, so by that (unwelcome) rule the poster has every right to post it.